# Referencing a specific object in a model ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

You have 3 models defined in models.py...

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    alpha = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bravo = models.DateTimeField()

class Baz(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    charlie = models.BooleanField()
```

... and you want to ensure that the `bar` object in `Baz` references the same `Foo` that `foo` in `Baz` references.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to design these models?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you actually want here. At the most basic level, you can run a check in the model's `clean` method

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.foo != self.bar.foo:
          raise ValidationError('Some error here')
```

However, if `Baz.foo`, must always be the same as `Baz.bar.foo`, then it makes no sense to have `foo` as attribute on `Baz`. If you need `foo`, just get it through the `bar` attribute.

Or, if you insist on data-redundancy, at least take the human variable out of the equation and simply set `Baz.foo` automatically:

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.foo = self.bar.foo
        super(Baz, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```